# Populating a multicolumn listview without a hashmap

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have been reading about multicolumn listviews today. They seem to be what I need, but can't info info about how to populate them not using a hash map. All examples I have seen use a hash map to build the listview data adapter but this is too heavy when lot of data is implied. Is there anyway to populate a list view without a hash list?

All examples I have seen use something like this:
http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com.es/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html

Comment: Any examples? I wasn't reading about multicolumn listviews today.

Comment: Where do you keep data? In database or something else?

Comment: Why not just an ArrayList of custom `Object`s? Or a `Cursor`?

Comment: dziobas: Database. @Michal K: Would you mind showing some code about how to bind the arraylist to the listview? I guess it would be something like a custom adapter.

Comment: In you case the best choice is CursorAdapter or subclasses

Comment: It's a simple `ArrayAdapter` - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html. I'll post some sample code as soon as the first half of the match finishes;) But if it's a sqlite database which returns a `Cursor`, then `CursorAdapter` is even better.

Comment: Oh, I see it's resolved. Good for you then:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. please Check out the code.

```
public class List_view_ArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context context;
    private String[] name;
    private String[] address;
    private String[] rating;
    private TextView nameTextView;
    private TextView addressTextView;
    private ImageView lisiconImageView;
    private AppManagers appManagers;

    public List_view_ArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] name,
            String[] address, String[] rating) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_layout, name);
        this.context = context;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.rating = rating;
        appManagers = new AppManagers();

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
        nameTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        addressTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.addressTextView);

        lisiconImageView = (ImageView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.listiconImageView);
        nameTextView.setText(name[position]);
        addressTextView.setText(address[position]);

        lisiconImageView.setImageDrawable(appManagers
                .ImageOperations(rating[position]));
        // imageView.setImageResource(imageid[position]);
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Here is list_layout for this line "R.layout.list_layout"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="#d9d9d9">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/listiconImageView"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name : "
                android:textColor="#2a170e" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#2a170e" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Address : "
                android:textColor="#2a170e" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/addressTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#2a170e" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Finaly you call it from your main Activity.

```
new List_view_ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter= new List_view_ArrayAdapter(context, appManagers.getNameArray(cafeandbarsList), name, address, rating); 

listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

I think it help you.

Thanks

Comment: A customAdapter seems to be the best option here.